# What is the name of the "username@hostname:~$" line?

Tags: command-line

Simple question! what is the name of the `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$` or the `username@hostname:~$` line? How should I refer to it?

Comment: It is called "prompt". Content of a terminal prompt can be controlled using `PS1` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be your [bash prompt](http://blog.twistedcode.org/2008/03/customizing-your-bash-prompt.html) or just "prompt". You might also use the tag you gave your question, it is a [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line).

Answer (score 4):

It has been called the *system prompt* for as long as I can remember.

The part before the `@` is the username, the part after it is the hostname.

Comment: Thanks! :D I'm glad you told me about the "username, hostname" thing.